# Locally path-connected implies that the components are open

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

If $X$ is a locally path-connected space, then its connected components are open.

I am trying to prove this, but for some reason it doesn't seem right to me, knowing that components are always closed. If the statement is true, wouldn't it be the case the components are the whole space $X$?

Comment: No, consider $X = (0,1) \cup (3,4)$. The components are open and closed.

Comment: Only if the space is connected :-)

Comment: Hey Jimmy, seems like you have the answer you gave me today. Perhaps you should accept it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

1) If $X$ is locally path-connected, then path components of $X$ are open
2) If $X$ is locally path-connected, then path components and connected components coincide

Answer (score 3):

Here's another proof. It uses two facts:

- the union of any non-disjoint connected subsets is connected
- path connected sets are connected

Suppose $C$ is a component of the locally path connected space $X$, and suppose it's not open. Then it must contain a boundary point, call it $b$. Since the space is locally path connected, we can find a neighborhood $V$ of $b$ that is path-connected.

But path-connected subsets are always connected. Also, $C$ and $V$ share the point $b$, so $C \cup V$ is a connected subset that is strictly larger than $C$ due to the fact that $V$, being a neighborhood of a boundary point of $C$, intersects $X - C$. This contradicts that $C$ is a *maximal connected subset* (since that is what components are).

So in fact $C$ must be open.

Comment: I would reformulate this by saying:
(a) a locally *connected* component is open
(b) in particular, a locally path connected set is connected
to emphasize the more general result (a)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a connected component $C$ of $X$.

(*) Given any point $x \in C$ there must exist an open set $V \subset X$ that is path-connected such that $x \in V$

> We say X is locally path connected if for every point $x \in X$ and every open neighborhood $U \subset X$ of $x$, there exists a open set $V \subset X$ that is path-connected and $x \in V \subset U$.

To get (*) just consider $U = X$ in the definition above.

Now, Since $V$ is path-connected then it must bet connected. And since $V \cap C \neq \emptyset$ ($x \in V\cap C$) this means $V \subset C$.

$C$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the connected components are open, it is sufficient that each point has a connected neighborhood.

If, moreover, each point has a neighborhood base of connected sets (we say $X$ is *locally connected*), then one can even show that every open subset of $X$ has only open connected components. Actually, the following are equivalent:

- $X$ is locally connected
- The components of each open subset are open
- Each point $x\in X$ has a local base of open connected sets

The same holds if we replace *connected* by *path connected* and *component* by *path component*, and the proofs are the same.
Also note that *path connected* implies *connected.*